# How to return only subset of elements from a JSONB field in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table in Postgres with the structure bellow.

| id | name | objects(jsonb) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first | `[{"name":"a", value:"1", "param":{}}, {"name":"b", "value":"55", "param":{}}, {"name":"c", "value":"234", "param":{}}]` |
| 2 | second | `[{"name":"b", "value":"22", "param":{}}, {"name":"c", "value":"24", "param":{}}]` |
| 3 | third | `[{"name":"c", "value":"345", "param":{}}] |` |
| 4 | forth | `[{"name":"a", "value":"123", "param":{}}, {"name":"b", "value":"456", "param":{}}]` |

I am trying to write a query that returns all the rows but with only a subset of the objects in the "objects" column.

The output bellow would be the answer in case I want only the elements with "name"="b"

| id | name | objects(jsonb) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first | [`{"name":"b", "value":"55", "param":{}}]` |
| 2 | second | `[{"name":"b", "value":"22", "param":{}}]` |
| 3 | third | `[]` |
| 4 | forth | `[{"name":"b", "value":"456", "param":{}}]` |

The output bellow would be the answer in case I want only the elements with "name"="b" or "name"="c"

| id | name | objects(jsonb) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first | [`{"name":"b", "value":"55", "param":{}}, {"name":"c", "value":"234", "param":{}}]` |
| 2 | second | `[{"name":"b", "value":"22", "param":{}}, {"name":"c", "value":"24", "param":{}}]` |
| 3 | third | `[{"name":"c", "value":"345", "param":{}}]` |
| 4 | forth | `[{"name":"b", "value":"456", "param":{}}]` |

Comment: FYI, the `jsonb` is not properly formatted. The key names need to be double quoted e.g `value` --> `"value"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) use `jsonb_path_query`:

```
SELECT
    jsonb_path_query('[{"name":"a", "value":"1", "param":{}}, {"name":"b", "value":"55", "param":{}}, 
{"name":"c", "value":"234", "param":{}}]'::jsonb, '$[*] ? (@.name == "b")');

 jsonb_path_query              
-------------------------------------------
 {"name": "b", "param": {}, "value": "55"}
```

**UPDATE** Second case:

```
SELECT
    jsonb_agg(a)
FROM 
    jsonb_path_query('[{"name":"a", "value":"1", "param":{}}, {"name":"b", "value":"55", "param":{}}, 
{"name":"c", "value":"234", "param":{}}]'::jsonb, '$[*] ? (@.name == "b" || @.name == "c")') AS t (a);


jsonb_agg                                        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"name": "b", "param": {}, "value": "55"}, {"name": "c", "param": {}, "value": "234"}]
```

Comment: thank you, this looks good, One issue I can have is if I want to see (@name=="b") ||  (@name=="c").  I would need to make a group by id, right?   I forgot to add this case in my original question.

Comment: See **UPDATE** for new query and if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Extract elements, filter, aggregate

```
select id, name, jsonb_agg(e) objects
from (
   select id, jsonb_array_elements(objects) e
   from mytable ) t
where e::jsonb ->> 'name' = 'b'
group by id, name
```

Comment: This works, is there a way to do it just from the select zone? Since i am just changing only a field's value.